# 2D density plot colored by factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I would like to represent my data (PCA) as two (even more) overlapping 2D density regions, colored by a specific factor. For each factor value, the most 'densely populated' area should be also darker than less populated regions.
I used `stat_density_2d()`:

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(PC1, PC2,colour=as.factor(class))) +
  stat_density_2d()
```

getting this plot:
[PCA with contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e65uM.png)

Then, I tried different combination of `stat_density_2d(aes())` arguments, such as `fill=`, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Hi Mattia, it would be best to add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question. you can achieve this by doing `dput(mydf)`

Comment: Thanks @Bushidov for the comment. I provide you with an example code, using the `iris` dataset: 

`library(ggplot2)
data("iris")
pc <- prcomp(iris[,-5], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
mydf <- cbind(pc$x,iris[,5,drop=F])

ggplot(mydf, aes(PC1, PC2,colour=Species)) +
  stat_density_2d()`